# How to remove double ticks in bar charts and remove/ extend space between bars?

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, charts

This is the bar chart. I need to remove the overextensions of the bar lines, reduce the space between consecutive A,B,C,D. However, I also want to retain/ add space between the three groups of `A-B-C-D`

```
BarChart[{{0.41, 0.70, 0, 0.52}, {0.09, 0.09, 1.2, 0.39}, {0.04, 0, 
   1.3, 0.38}}, ChartLabels -> {"A", "B", "C", "D"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Trawling through the documentation of `BarChart`

```
BarChart[
 {{0.41, 0.70, 0, 0.52}, {0.09, 0.09, 1.2, 0.39}, {0.04, 0, 1.3,0.38}},
 ChartLabels -> {"A", "B", "C", "D"},
 TicksStyle -> Opacity[0],(*remove tick marks near labels*)
 LabelStyle -> Opacity[1],(*keep labels*)
 BarSpacing -> {None,Large} (* {distance between bars, distance between groups}*)
 ]
```

[image: sdsd]

**EDIT**

As highlighted by Domen in the comments
`TicksStyle -> {Opacity[0], Automatic}`
might be a better solution as I have also stripped the tickmarks on the y-axis

Comment: Note that this also removes ticks on the y axis, which might not be desirable. ``TicksStyle -> {Opacity[0], Automatic}`` might be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks @Domen, I failed to notice that and can imagine being frustrated later on as to why they were missing! I will edit the post to highlight your comment

Comment: `TicksStyle -> {LineOpacity -> 0,  Automatic} ` gives the desired result without having to specify `LabelStyle`.